# installing pyalsaaudio on raspberry pi zero W (raspbian OS)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pyaudio

Hi everyone, 
I tried everything to install pyalsaaudio package on my Raspberry Pi Zero W 
can anyone please help me with a guide to install it on my device ?
I see a lot of guides for Ubunto OS and i even tried them on my device but nothing worked for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: a little update :
i managed to install the package, (needed apt-get upgrade..)
but when i try to import that package it doesnt recognize it.
"no module named alsaaudio..."

Answer (score -2):

there is a adafruit tutorial which works just perfect. 
You have to install some libraries before, reboot at a certain point for them to make efect and last you enable the module.

Here is the link https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test#

Hope it works!